# why when creating e2-small it shows it has 2 vCPU and when checking configuration it shows it has only 1 vCPU on gcp?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, vcpu

- This is what I get when creating a e2-small machine
  [image]
- This is what I get when checking the machine after creation:
  [image]
- This is what is shown on the page https://cloud.google.com/compute/vm-instance-pricing:
  [image]

*This is what I get when using cat /proc/cpuinfo:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your first screenshot, it shows **e2-small (2 vCPU, 2 GB memory).

In your second screenshot, it shows **1 shared core**.

One CPU core is 2 vCPUs. Therefore, your first and second screenshots are showing the same thing.

A vCPU is a **hyper-thread**. Each CPU core consists of two hyper-threads.

> How does Hyper-Threading work? When Intel® Hyper-Threading Technology
> is active, the CPU exposes two execution contexts per physical core.
> This means that one physical core now works like two “logical cores”
> that can handle different software threads.

[What Is Hyper-Threading?](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/gaming/resources/hyper-threading.html)

Comment: You should also see two processor entries when running  ```cat /proc/cpuinfo```.